# Apple In App Purchase with Introductory Offer (SKProductDiscountPaymentModePayUpFront)

Tags: swift, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I am writing a SwiftUI app and I am looking for some advice.

I setup a product identifier in AppStore connect

Lets say it's

> com.example.subscription_service_1

The monthly price is $39.99

I want to have an introductory offer for $19.99 if a buyer chooses a 12 month pay up front

```
SKProductDiscountPaymentModePayUpFront
```

When the IAP is triggered, the customer ONLY gets to see ONE option. They see the Pay Up Front.

I am not sure if I am doing something wrong or if this is how it's designed.
I felt that Apple always allowed customers to choose their options.

Please advise what I must do (without creating unnecessary product Identifiers).

Comment: Hi, @software is fun can you code how to implement intro offers in ios? I am seeing any sheet about intro offers to the user.

Comment: @Lakshmi yes I can. My App is still in development and this was very difficult to implement in my app. The documentation was very sketchy at that time.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand you correctly, but if you want to charge the user $39.99 monthly and grant him an introductory offer when he chooses one year, then you have to create two subscriptions: one monthly subscription with the price of $39.99 and a yearly subscription with a price of whatever you want. You then have to create the introductory offer of $19.99 within App Store Connect for the yearly subscription.

Comment: I did but the user never gets a choice of selecting the monthly $39.99 or the pay upfront ($239.99). The IAP Sheet only presents the $239.99 if the user is eligible for the introductory offer.

Comment: How do you determine the available IAPs in your app?

Comment: I have simply added the product identifier to AppStore connect. In my specific case, I have 3 identifiers (3 products). One product has a FREE Trial, the other 2 have an introductory offer (pay up front). But when I select the other 2, Apple only displays the payUpFront option. The dollar amount is for the year so Im afraid that without a choice to the user, they may choose not to make any purchase. It's like choose to pay $240 for the first year then $40/month or nothing. I expected it to be an option between pay $240 for the first year OR pay $40/month.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand you correctly. You have three products: One with a free trial (product1) and two with `payUpFront` (product2 and product3). You are able to display all three products, but for product2 and product3, your sheet shows only the pay up front prices?